# Highcharts tooltip x axis font size

Tags: javascript, highcharts

from the highcharts api it says we can edit the fontsize in the tooltip, however, this only edits the values and not the x axis label.

[image]

Is there a way to increase the size of the Tuesday, May 17... etc as well? i.e. the x axis label?

Editing the real xaxis label did not work.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi, I think that in your case you can set useHTML of your tooltip to true and format your tooltip using css. Here you can see very simple example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/dpf8qq4y/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom tooltips formatting, you can use the formatter property to pass a function which returns your custom html.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    }, 
useHTML: true
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saxko6p4/)

More info [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, This doesn't seem to work for my purposes though, the font size does not change. Am I doing this correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/vpz853o1/